# (AS3/Flash/AIR) Should I use System.disposeXML() on every XML in a generated XMLList?

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, flash, garbage-collection, air

Let's say this is an external `XML` that I load at the beginning:

```
<food>
  <sandwich name="burger"/>
  <sandwich name="sub"/>
  <pasta name="linguini"/>
  <pasta name="penne">
</food>
```

Then I get an `XMLList` of the sandwiches by doing this:

```
const sandwichList:XMLList = food.sandwich;
```

That `XMLList` just created two new `XML`'s, one for each sandwich right? They are copies, not references to the original XML? If they are copies, does that mean I should use `System.disposeXML()` on each of them when I am done to get them garbage collected?

Comment: No, I don't think they are copies. But you could actually check it really fast, faster then asking here at least : ))) Just do **sandwichList[0].@aaa = "bbb";** then **trace(food);**

Answer (score 0):

Reading [this Adobe help](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e71.html), XMLs made by whatever calling of XML-creation methods are copies, not references. Yet, leaving the local variable visibility *should* implicitly allow GC to collect orphaned XML nodes like your sandwich list, so explicit call of `System.disposeXML()` is not necessary. However, you might decide to check actual behavior of AS3 by allocating a rather large `XMLList` within a function several times, then checking for [`System.freeMemory`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#freeMemory) before you generate XMLs, while the created XMLs are visible and after leaving that code and explicitly calling `System.gc()`.